# Visual Studio 2013 making weird problems with reopened WP8 solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I've been using Visual Studio 2013 with WP8 SDK for awhile. But lately I started to have some weird problems. When I create a new project, everything works fine. But after closing VS and reopening the solution, I get tons of errors, from basically nowhere.

Empty project -> Save -> Exit VS -> Reopen and this happens.

[image]

Comment: Does this happen only when you work with WP8 SDK or also with any other project in VS?
Do you use some plugin?

Comment: I dont have anything else installed, it happens only with WP8 projects and only in XML files, C# (.cs) files work. I'm gonna download VS 2012 Ultimate from MSDNAA, maybe that's VS2013's fault, I don't know.

Comment: Try cleaning solution and rebuilding it.